# How to handle validation for Redux-Form FieldArrays with Immutable.js?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm currently using redux-form/immutable, Wizard-Form, and FieldArrays to create a multi-step form for a project. I'm basically getting stuck on how to validate the field arrays with immutable.js.

I've followed the following example: https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/examples/immutable/ to setup validation in validate.js file with immutable but I also had to follow the following example https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/examples/fieldarrays/ to figure out how to do validation for FieldArrays.

By following both examples I came up with the following:

```
if (values.get('customTrips')) {
    const customTripArrayErrors = [];
    values.get('customTrips').forEach((member, memberIndex) => {
      const customTripMemberErrors = {};
      if (!member.get('from_location_address1') {
      }
    }
}
```

When I try the above code I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

I just need help figuring out how to access FieldArray member values in validate.js.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea was right but I missed an important step when pushing to a Redux-Form FieldArray. You need to make sure when you push, you are creating a new Map so that you can access the values with get. If you don't create a new Map and you console.log(member), you will see that it is undefined. Hope this helps as this was not written in the Redux-Form docs!

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';

<FlatButton
  type="button"
  onClick={() => fields.push(new Map())}
  backgroundColor={Color.primary}
  hoverColor={Color.primaryDarkened}
  className="left"
  label="Add a Local Trip"
/>
```